# How to create facebook fan page for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I've created fanpage of the app in facebook. Wonder how to create the button "Download App" like it shows in "Seesmic" fanpage.

http://www.facebook.com/seesmic

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the app settings, under "Facebook Integration", in the "Canvas" section. All the fields should be empty.